# How to recover a dropped mysql database with its procedures?

Tags: mysql

I had some databases on a server and MySqlserver on this server has been uninstalled accidentally by someone. I had some backups on this server and could recover all tables and their data successfully but the problem is that the events and procedures are lost. I searched a lot to know if it is possible or not and how I can recover lost events and procedures.

Answer (score 1):

They should be part of a good backup. If they are not, and the mysql data directory was deleted, they are irrevocably gone. Events and procedures are entities inside a database just like tables.